# Setting up a counter to know in which number to start

Tags: python, counter, pickle, python-3.4

I want the following counter to check the order num class inside a dictionary thats inside a list.

```
...code...
self.counter = count(1)
def submit(self):

        if Database.xoomDatabase[0]["Num Orden"] == next(self.counter):
            self.counter = Database.xoomDatabase["Num Orden"]
        Database.xoomDatabase.append(ordenOrganiz)
```

The reason I'm doing this type of counter is because I'm dumping a pickle file everytime the app closes, that contains Database.xoomDatabase. When the app is executed, the pickle dump gets loaded and all the dictionaries inside of it get pushed back into Database.xoomDatabase. This is the dictionary that's saved on Database.xoomDatabase:

```
global ordenOrganiz
        ordenOrganiz = {"Num Order": nicenum,
                        "Nombre": nombre, 
                        "Email": email,
                        "Num Tel/Cel": num,
                        "Orden Creada:": fechacreacion1,
                        "Fecha de Entrega": fechaentrega}
        print(ordenOrganiz["Nombre"])
        return dict(ordenOrganiz)
```

My questions is: How can I start the counter in exactly the last "Order Num" the is loaded from the pickle dump file?

EDIT:
This is how, with the help of Anand S Kumar, I got it it to work:

```
if len(Database.xoomDatabase) == 0:
            newCount = 0
        else:
            newCount = max(Database.xoomDatabase, key = lambda x:x['Num Orden'])["Num Orden"]
        nombre = contents1
        nicenum = int(newCount) + 1
```

This loop checks if there are any saved dictionaries on the list. If there ar no dics., the count starts at 1. If there are already saved dics., the count will start from the last "Orden Num"(Order Number) saved into the pickle dump.

```
xoomDatabase = []
if path.isfile(file_path) == False:
    open(file_path, "w").close()
else:
    loadLis = open(file_path, "rb")
    dalis = pickle.load(loadLis)
    loadLis.close()
    xoomDatabase.extend(dalis)
```

This loops check if there is any file to load, if there isn't, it cretes one. If there's already a saved pickle dump, then it will load the list with previously saved dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class variable directly inside the class, and then access it using `Class.<variable>` and also in `__init__()` function use this `Class.<variable>` to initialize the counter for each variable and increment the counter.

Example -

```
class TempClass
    counterInit = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter = TempClass.counterInit
        TempClass.counterInit += 1
    ...
```

And then at the start of the program, read back the data from the pickle dump and then take the largest counter and set it to counter as given in below example.

Example -

```
TempClass.counterInit = max(Database.xoomDatabase, key = lambda x:x['Num Orden'])
```

The above `max()` gives the largest `Num Orden` from the list of dictionaries.

Comment: I had a counter set up on the __init__() of my function like you said, what is counterVal in your suggestion? It's kind of confusing..

Comment: counterVal is the passed in value of the counter, passed in when creating the object I indicated in the lines after that

Comment: But the counter should initialize with the order num from the last invoice created.. How will the tempObject var you suggested pass the correct or num to the self.counter?

Comment: How do you determine the last invoice created ? Where does that come from?

Comment: A pickle dump. Let me explain better. What I'm doing is creating invoices which get numbered order num #1-#5(for example), when I terminate the app, the invoices are stored in a list which is stored in a file through pickle dump. Now, when I open my app again and load my pickle file, my counter restarts to order num #1 again, instead of the last order num stored in the pickle file..

Comment: Then you should define a class variable , not inside the `__init__()` function, but directly in the class (I will update the answer with an example) then at the start of the program, read back the list form the pickle dump and then `list[-1]` should give you the last element, you take that counter and do `TempClass.counter = thatNumber` .

Comment: I'm stumped with this. self.counter = Database.xoomDatabase["Orden Num"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: is that a list? the list of dictionaries? Then iterate over them using `for i in Database.xoomDataBase:` then do `i["Order Num"]` , use that iteration to get the largest order num and set it as `counterInit`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81308/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-feners).